# Mask redirected URL

Tags: .htaccess

I have an URL that redirects to another. (Both sites are hosted by myself)

How can I mask the final URL to show the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy answer: You cannot. The browser (or any script accessing the content at that given URL) shows the user where the data is coming from - and that's the redirection target, since that's where the data is coming from.

The complx answer: You can. However this required quite a bit of work. The server internally has to fetch the data for the redirection target and forward it to the client. However strictly speaking this isn't a redirect any more that you can perform using a .htacess configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I knew one site who was offering free domains but no hosting was doing this (the adress bar always showed the free domain no matter where the archives where).
But I just found out, it was doing this with an iframe lol >_> I've been killing myself to find the answer for a few days and it was a width=100% height=100% iframe .... Thanks anyways